# Export data to different excel sheets in R shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, xlsx

I'm wondering which package can be used in a Shiny App to export data to excel file. 
I know I can use xlsx, but it requires RJava and I fear that other users can't install it.

Comment: Take a look to openxlsx package.. You can even apply style to your sheets..

Comment: Agreed wit Ika8. +1 for `openxlsx`.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily export data to Excel using a download button and base R. Then your file would be a csv-file, which can be easily opened in Excel. An example could be: 
https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/download.html

Would a csv-File be sufficient or do you absolutely need an xlsx-file?

Comment: Actually, I'd would like to export data to a first sheet, and some informations to a second sheet (all in the same excel file). I don't think it is possible with a csv-File :/